# Inherited blocks are not processed

Tags: pug, hexo

Using Hexo with Pug as the templating engine, I have a main layout, a default for all my pages (`layout.pug`):

```
doctype html
html
    header
    body
        block nav
            p hello
        // logic of page decision goes here
        div This is the footer of the page
```

I want to keep the `nav` part in a separate file (`p hello` is just a placeholder for debugging) so I created `nav.pug`:

```
extends layout

block nav
    div
        p --- navigation common to all pages ---
```

When building the site I systematically get as the HTML output

```
<!DOCTYPE 5>
<html>
<header></header>

<body>
    <p>hello</p>
    <!-- logic of page decision goes here-->
    <div>This is the footer of the page</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**The `nav` block is not replaced, why?**

The a build with `--debug` shows that `nav.pug` is processed:

```
PS D:\MegaSync\dev-perso\blog-vuetify\blog> hexo clean ; hexo g --debug
INFO  Deleted database.
INFO  Deleted public folder.
13:20:07.849 DEBUG Hexo version: 3.5.0
13:20:07.853 DEBUG Working directory: D:\MegaSync\dev-perso\blog-vuetify\blog\
13:20:07.975 DEBUG Config loaded: D:\MegaSync\dev-perso\blog-vuetify\blog\_config.yml
13:20:07.988 DEBUG Plugin loaded: hexo-generator-archive
(...)
13:20:08.367 DEBUG Plugin loaded: hexo-server
13:20:08.394 DEBUG Loading database.
13:20:08.401 INFO  Start processing
13:20:08.425 DEBUG Processed: _posts/second.md
13:20:08.427 DEBUG Processed: layout/index.pug
13:20:08.429 DEBUG Processed: layout/nav.pug      <--- HERE
13:20:08.431 DEBUG Processed: _posts/first.md
13:20:08.432 DEBUG Processed: layout/layout.pug
13:20:08.432 DEBUG Processed: layout/post.pug
13:20:08.503 DEBUG Generator: page
13:20:08.504 DEBUG Generator: post
13:20:08.505 DEBUG Generator: archive
13:20:08.505 DEBUG Generator: index
13:20:08.506 DEBUG Generator: category
13:20:08.506 DEBUG Generator: tag
13:20:08.507 DEBUG Generator: asset
13:20:08.510 INFO  Files loaded in 116 ms
13:20:08.514 DEBUG Rendering post: posts/second/index.html
13:20:08.521 DEBUG Rendering post: posts/first/index.html
13:20:08.523 DEBUG Rendering index: archives/index.html
13:20:08.525 DEBUG Rendering index: archives/2018/index.html
13:20:08.526 DEBUG Rendering index: archives/2018/02/index.html
13:20:08.528 DEBUG Rendering index: index.html
13:20:08.530 DEBUG Rendering index: tags/tech/index.html
13:20:08.699 INFO  Generated: index.html
13:20:08.702 INFO  Generated: archives/index.html
13:20:08.704 INFO  Generated: posts/second/index.html
13:20:08.705 INFO  Generated: posts/first/index.html
13:20:08.706 INFO  Generated: archives/2018/02/index.html
13:20:08.708 INFO  Generated: archives/2018/index.html
13:20:08.709 INFO  Generated: tags/tech/index.html
13:20:08.711 INFO  7 files generated in 201 ms
13:20:10.562 DEBUG Database saved
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Hexo uses `layout.[pug|ejs|etc]` as the parent template for defining the site's structure, if you try using anything else, it will be ignored. Hexo processes everything in asset or template folders, including templates that don't actually correspond to a page.

If you really wanted to use `extends` in this manner, you'd have to create another Pug template that you would extend inside `layout.pug`, so the code you currently have in `nav.pug` would have to go inside `layout`.

You might be better off, however, turning the nav into a partial that you can add some conditional logic too (ex: accessing Hexo's global `path` variable to see if a given link matches a path and apply styling accordingly). You can then use `include nav.pug` instead.

For instance, you can do something like this.

**layout.pug**

```
doctype html
html
    header
    body
        block nav
            p hello
        include nav.pug
        // logic of page decision goes here
        div This is the footer of the page
```

**nav.pug**

```
- items = ['archive', 'foo', 'home']
nav
  for i in items 
    a.link(href='/' + i, class="" + path.includes(i) ? 'active' : '')
```